Audio playback from a WebSockets endpoint on the Web
I have a web application with FastAPI backend and a web frontend. I would like to be able to play the audio via WebSockets on the client. The reason for that is that the user has a bunch of other interactions via WebSockets and I would like to use only one endpoint to keep track of the state.
The problem: the audio via WebSockets is very choppy, whereas when I load the same logic via streaming/audio request it's just fine. So I am looking to make them equivalent.
Here's the backend:
@router.websocket('/audio_ws')
async def audio_sockets(ws: WebSocket):
    await ws.accept()

    file = wave.open('my_file.wav', 'rb')
    CHUNK = 1024

    with open('paper_to_audio/data/paper.wav', 'rb') as file_like:
        while True:
            next = file_like.read(CHUNK)
            if next == b'':
                file_like.close()
                break
            await ws.send_bytes(next)


@router.get("/audio")
def read_audio():
    def iterfile():
        CHUNK = 1024
        with open('my_file.wav', 'rb') as file_like:
            while True:
                next = file_like.read(1024)
                if next == b'':
                    file_like.close()
                    break
                yield next
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="audio/wav")

As you can see, the logic for reading the file is basically identical.
Here's the frontend code for reading from streaming, which works like a charm:
<audio preload="none" controls id="audio">
   <source src="/audio" type="audio/wav">
</audio>


Here's the JavaScript for reading from WebSockets:
        function playAudioFromBackend() {
            const sample_rate = 44100; // Hz

            // Websocket url
            const ws_url = "ws://localhost:8000/audio_ws"

            let audio_context = null;
            let ws = null;

            async function start() {
                if (ws != null) {
                    return;
                }

                // Create an AudioContext that plays audio from the AudioWorkletNode  
                audio_context = new AudioContext();
                await audio_context.audioWorklet.addModule('audioProcessor.js');
                const audioNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audio_context, 'audio-processor');
                audioNode.connect(audio_context.destination);

                // Setup the websocket 
                ws = new WebSocket(ws_url);
                ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

                // Process incoming messages
                ws.onmessage = (event) => {
                    // Convert to Float32 lpcm, which is what AudioWorkletNode expects
                    const int16Array = new Int16Array(event.data);
                    let float32Array = new Float32Array(int16Array.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < int16Array.length; i++) {
                        float32Array[i] = int16Array[i] / 32768.;
                    }

                    // Send the audio data to the AudioWorkletNode
                    audioNode.port.postMessage({ message: 'audioData', audioData: float32Array });
                }

                ws.onopen = () => {
                    console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
                };

                ws.onclose = () => {
                    console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
                };

                ws.onerror = error => {
                    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
                };
            }

            async function stop() {
                console.log('Stopping audio');
                if (audio_context) {
                    await audio_context.close();
                    audio_context = null;
                    ws.close();
                    ws = null;
                }
            }

            start()

And the associated worklet:
class AudioProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.buffer = new Float32Array();

        // Receive audio data from the main thread, and add it to the buffer
        this.port.onmessage = (event) => {
            let newFetchedData = new Float32Array(this.buffer.length + event.data.audioData.length);
            newFetchedData.set(this.buffer, 0);
            newFetchedData.set(event.data.audioData, this.buffer.length);
            this.buffer = newFetchedData;
        };
    }

    // Take a chunk from the buffer and send it to the output to be played
    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        const output = outputs[0];
        const channel = output[0];
        const bufferLength = this.buffer.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < channel.length; i++) {
            channel[i] = (i < bufferLength) ? this.buffer[i] : 0;
        }
        this.buffer = this.buffer.slice(channel.length);
        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('audio-processor', AudioProcessor);

What am I doing wrong? Why is the audio choppy?

It looks like your code doesn't use the sample_rate variable. It's possible that your audio is in 44.1kHz but the AudioContext is running at 48kHz. If you don't account for that there will not be enough samples to fill the audio output buffers.
The easiest way to avoid that is by forcing the AudioContext to run at the desired sample rate. It will then resample internally.
audio_context = new AudioContext({
    sampleRate: sample_rate
});

It's also possible that the WebSocket connection doesn't send the audio at the required rate.
